# OpenLayers 3 displaying a vector layer

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, vector, geojson, openlayers

I have GeoJSON that happily displays on [GeoJson.IO](http://geojson.io) that I am trying to display on a vector layer in an OpenLayers 3 map.

The GeoJSON is in EPSG:4326, the map is in EPSG:3857.

My code is:

```
view = new ol.View(
{
    // make sure the view doesn't go beyond the 19 zoom levels
    maxZoom: 10,
    projection: "EPSG:3857"
});
map = new ol.Map(
{
    layers: layers,
    controls: ol.control.defaults(),
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults(
        {
            altShiftDragRotate: false,
            dragPan: true,
            rotate: false
        })
        .extend([new ol.interaction.DragPan(
        {
            kinetic: null
        })]),
    // renderer: CANVAS,
    // Improve user experience by loading tiles while dragging/zooming. Will make
    // zooming choppy on mobile or slow devices.
    loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
    target: 'map',
    view: view
});
    activationvectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            projection: "EPSG:4326"
            });
    activationLayer = new ol.layer.Vector(
    {
        title: 'Activation Boundary',
        source: activationvectorSource,
        style: new ol.style.Style(
        {
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke(
            {
            color: 'red', width: 2
            })
         })
    });
    map.addLayer(activationLayer);
    activationvectorSource.addFeatures(data);
```

I know I am missing something obvious, but I simply cannot get it to display

What am I missing?

GeoJSON (if needed):

```
    {
       "type":"FeatureCollection",
       "features":[
          {
             "type":"Feature",
             "geometry":{
                "type":"Polygon",
                "coordinates":[
                   [
                      [
                         34.628906243797,
                         -3.3379539608193
                      ],
                      [
                         -69.477539050055,
                         -1.4061088351833
                      ],
                      [
                         -70.00488279996,
                         -1.3182430566259
                      ],
                      [
                         -71.191406237248,
                         0.043945308183483
                      ],
                      [
                         -71.191406237248,
                         0.30761570958881
                      ],
                      [
                         44.824218741971,
                         34.813803311646
                      ],
                      [
                         45.527343741845,
                         34.813803311646
                      ],
                      [
                         90.354309065846,
                         23.762723177664
                      ],
                      [
                         125.3814697041,
                         12.280966403201
                      ],
                      [
                         125.51330564158,
                         12.189703801854
                      ],
                      [
                         125.51879880564,
                         12.184334433131
                      ],
                      [
                         125.51879880564,
                         12.17359536978
                      ],
                      [
                         125.4968261494,
                         12.033948161512
                      ],
                      [
                         125.45837400096,
                         11.990965148066
                      ],
                      [
                         34.980468743734,
                         -3.3379539608193
                      ],
                      [
                         34.628906243797,
                         -3.3379539608193
                      ]
                   ]
                ]
             },
             "properties":{
                "extent":"POLYGON((-71.28123776566 -3.42762895713832,-71.28123776566 34.8875230280736,125.608630334052 34.8875230280736,125.608630334052 -3.42762895713832,-71.28123776566 -3.42762895713832))",
                "activationid":"HOT-0013"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to read features using `format`.

```js
data=' your GeoJSON goes here ';
var activationLayer = new ol.layer.Vector(
    {
        title: 'Activation Boundary',
        source: new ol.source.GeoJSON(),
        style: new ol.style.Style(
        {
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke(
            {
            color: 'red', width: 2
            })
         })
    });

map.addLayer(activationLayer);   
var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON(); 
activationLayer.getSource().addFeatures( format.readFeatures( data, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
} ) );
```

Additionally, I had to set center and zoom for the view. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zzahmbff/11/), which displays your sample data.

Comment: Thanks Just tried it, no joy, I am obviously missing something obvious, but I cannot see it .. I also tried       projection: "EPSG:3857",
      defaultProjection: "EPSG: 4326"

Comment: Close, but I need to be able to add data to the layer after it is created, I tried vS.addFeatures(data) but so far no result.

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: Where did you find that?? That did the trick. Have never seen getSource(). Well done ..

Comment: I extracted it from a project I worked on few months ago, I guess it's in OL3 docs.